# extracting a string from html using HTMLParser & Python2.7

Tags: python, html, regex, string, python-2.7

I am developing an Alexa skill and therefore, I have the standard Python (2.7) libraries available for us. Therefore, I don't have BeautifulSoup4 available to use.

I'm trying to identify the below string within a full HTML page and then extract the string '104 spaces' from within the below. "104 spaces" is a variable however the other code remains constant:-

```
<p class="jp1"><strong>Car Parking</strong>104 spaces</p>
```

Is this possible to do with HTMLParser or alternatively, could this be done using a regex search? I appreciate regex is not the best for parsing HTML code however given I am using *urllib2* which processes the HTML code as a string and the fact I am looking to extract a specific string that follows a specific string within this, it may suffice in this case.

One option I am thinking of is:-

```
s1 = "<strong>Car Parking</strong>104 spaces</p>"
s2 = "<strong>Car Parking</strong>"

print s1[s1.index(s2) + len(s2):]
```

This will return all of the text commencing with "104 spaces" and onwards. Therefore, how can I isolate this specific segment of text?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I dont use python but here a regex. After this you need to replace the strong and p tag manually with python should be easy.

```
var test = '<p class="jp1"><strong>Car Parking</strong>104 spaces</p>'

test = test.match(/[<][/]strong[>](.*)[<][/]p[>]/gmi)
//console.log would be here test:  [ '</strong>104 spaces</p>' ]
test = test.join('')
test = test.replace('</strong>','')
test = test.replace('</p>','')

console.log('test: ', test)
```